# recipe for target 'runtime_ccall.o' failed in installing julia (llvm?)

Tags: julia, llvm

I just downloaded and installed the latest version of linux mint, mate. I want to install `julia` again but I get an strange error during the installation of v1.3.0

```
(... lots of output)
/home/usr/julia/usr/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:545:38:   required from here
/home/usr/julia/usr/include/llvm/Support/MathExtras.h:189:16: error: ‘static_assert’ was not declared in this scope
Makefile:165: recipe for target 'runtime_ccall.o' failed
make[1]: *** [runtime_ccall.o] Error 1
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'julia-src-release' failed
make: *** [julia-src-release] Error 2
```

This is somehow strange, but it appears to be related to LLVM. In trying to update LLVM I typed

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get install -y llvm
```

But the error keeps showing... any idea what am I missing?